# getting repeated result mysql query

Tags: mysql, select, join

Here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.emp_id,
    a.shift_id,
    a.shift_start_date,
    DATE((b.shift_start_date) - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS shift_end_date
FROM
    temp_shift a
        LEFT JOIN
    temp_shift b ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id
        AND a.shift_id != b.shift_id
        AND a.shift_start_date < b.shift_start_date
WHERE
    a.active = 'Y'
GROUP BY a.emp_id , a.shift_id , a.shift_start_date
ORDER BY a.emp_id , a.shift_start_date
```

i'm trying to get shift end date based on next shift change. i'm getiing result good. but my problem is i dont want results to be like 1-5,2-5,3-5,4-5,5-5,6-7(dates) it should be 1-5,6-7(dates).

[screenshot for my query and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLA1b.png)

Comment: This question appears to be ON topic to me (although it has been answered before), so I cannot agree with the close vote

Comment: please link the topic. that would be helpfull

Comment: This is a sequence starts and ends problem

Comment: but how to solve that?

Comment: What do you expected based on the data on your screenshot?

Comment: i expect that for empid 18060 shift_start-date is 2016-01-05 and shift_end_date is 2016-01-09. again in next row its from 2016-01-06 to 2016-01-09 and so on. i dont want date in between 05 to 09 again in result. after shift_start-date is 2016-01-05 and shift_end_date is 2016-01-09.  i want 2016-01-12 to 2016-01-16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"but how to solve that?"

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t(id INT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(6),(7),(8); 

SELECT a.id start
     , MIN(c.id) end 
  FROM t a
  LEFT 
  JOIN t b 
    ON b.id = a.id - 1
  LEFT 
  JOIN t c 
    ON c.id >= a.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN t d  
    ON d.id = c.id + 1
 WHERE b.id IS NULL 
   AND c.id IS NOT NULL
   AND d.id IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY a.id; 
+-------+------+
| start | end  |
+-------+------+
|     1 |    4 |
|     6 |    8 |
+-------+------+
```

Comment: Works good. but For my database i have more that 6k rows so its taking around 2min to execute the whole query

Comment: @KeyurShah This solution doesn't scale well. However, 6000 rows is nothing. Index your table, and try again. Post the EXPLAIN above if you're still struggling.